# How to convert librdkafka payload to json to get a parameter value?

Tags: c, apache-kafka, librdkafka, jansson

I'm playing around with the [consumer.c example file](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/consumer.c) for librdkafka and I'm trying to figure out how to convert the rkm payload (that is printed out at line 244) to json so that I can grab a parameter's value from the json.

Right now I'm using [jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.12/tutorial.html) but am having some problems with it which I can expand on if needed.

Is there a feature for this in librdkafka or the standard C libraries that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the message payload (binary) and length to Jansson, like so:

```c
/* For each consumed message .. */
rd_kafka_message_t *rkmessage = rd_kafka_consumer_poll(consumer, 1000);

if (!rkmessage) {
   /* No message available */
   continue;

} else if (rkmessage->err) {
   /* Handle consumer event/error (typically not fatal) */
   handle_consumer_error(rkmessage->err, "%s", rd_kafka_message_errstr(rkmessage));

} else if (rkmessage->len > 0) {
   /* Parse JSON value */
   json_error_t err;
   json_t *json = json_loadb(rkm->payload, rkm->len, JSON_ALLOW_NUL, &err);
   if (!json) {
      handle_consumer_error(RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__BAD_MSG,
                            "Failed to parse JSON for message at %s [%"PRId32"] offset %"PRIu64: line %d: %s\n",
                            rd_kafka_topic_name(rkmessage->rkt), rkmessage->partition),
                            rkmessage->offset, err.line, err.text);
   } else {
      /* Process the message */
      process_message(json);

      json_decref(json);
   }
}

rd_kafka_message_destroy(rkmessage);
```

See the Jansson docs for more info: https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: Is handle_consumer_error() and process_message() apart of librdkafka or jansson? I get the response `undefined reference to process_message'` when I use them.

Comment: Those are your functions, i.e., what you do on consumer error (typically just log), and how you process the received message.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, I used `json_t *json = json_loads(rkm->payload, rkm->len, & err);` and the if statement was executed meaning there was an error. Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: You can't use json_loads() (string) since the payload is not null-terminated, you need to use json_loadb() (binary) as in the example above.